# Typescript - Property does not exist on type

Tags: typescript

I have the following types

```js
export interface IResponseModel {
    hasError: boolean;
    message: string;
    statusCode: number;
    status: string;
}
export interface IDataResponseModel<T> extends IResponseModel {
    data?: T;
}
export interface StringResponseModel extends IDataResponseModel<string> {}
export class ErrorResponseModel implements IResponseModel {
    hasError: boolean;
    message: string;
    statusCode: number;
    status: string;
    constructor(message: string, statusCode: number, status: string = 'error') {
        this.hasError = true;
        this.message = message;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
export class ErrorObjectResponseModel extends ErrorResponseModel implements IDataResponseModel<any> {
    data?: any;
    constructor(message: string, statusCode: number, status: string = 'error', data?: any) {
        super(message, statusCode, status);
        this.data = data;
    }
}
export declare type ResponseModel =
    | ErrorObjectResponseModel
    | IResponseModel
    | ErrorResponseModel
    | StringResponseModel
    | IDataResponseModel<any>;
```

which then I've a method that returns the ResponseModel type, like

```js
import type { ResponseModel } from '@/models/api/response/commons';
async function get(): Promise<ResponseModel>
{
//not important code
}
```

I'm getting the following error while handling this result:

```
 Property 'data' does not exist on type 'ResponseModel'.
 Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IResponseModel'.
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Because `response` is of type `ResponseModel` which includes the type `IResponseModel`, and `IResponseModel` doesn't have the `data` property. You have to check if the `data` property exists before accesing it. For example with: `"data" in response`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `ResponseModel` type is a lot of possible types:

```
export declare type ResponseModel =
    | ErrorObjectResponseModel
    | IResponseModel
    | ErrorResponseModel
    | StringResponseModel
    | IDataResponseModel<any>;
```

Looking at what each of those are, only `ErrorObjectResponseModel` and `IDataResponseModel` have the `data` property on it.  The rest do not.

So if you expect that property to be there you either need to change the typing on the `get` method to return the **exact** type you are expecting, like this:

```
async function get(): Promise<ErrorObjectResponseModel> {
  //not important code
}
```

or you need to narrow the type when you get your data back, like this:

```
if(response instanceof ErrorObjectResponseModel){
  console.log(response.data); //data exists now that we know what type it is
  //...
}
```